# Paytm Payment Successful Redirect Issue-PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, paytm

In my site, I have an issue in the payment redirect URL. I'm using **PHP** as backend and **AngularJS** as front end. I'm using the app **Paytm** for payment.

When I click on **Place Order** button, I redirect to payment gateway page. After successful payment, the URL of site does not go to the Success page, instead, it redirects to Empty Cart Page. I want to display my order details after successful transaction and not redirect to an empty cart page.

How can I display my Order details?

```
define('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT', 'TEST'); // PROD
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', 'tN22ez5q2MCg5KzE3'); 
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', 'xxx57900025939441'); 
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'abcde');
define('CALLBACK_URL','http://sample.in/sample/Testdata/app/PaytmKit/pgResponse.php');
```

Comment: The answer is in the code! Edit some into your question. But it really just sounds like you're not sending the right data to the payment processing site. Check what data is being sent and compare to examples in the documentation.

Comment: I added some codes here.. pls check now.. its really urgent

Comment: What you have there will not be enough for anyone to answer the question.  Please create a [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.